# Why is my MS Access query not updateable

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

[image]

Hi guys,

This has been troubling me as of late. Access says this query is not updateable. How can I get this to be updateable?

When I remove tblMasterContracts1, it is updateable, but that doesn't fit my goal. Is this a limitation of relational databases in general?

SQL:

```
SELECT tblBuildings.[Building Address]
FROM (tblBuildings INNER JOIN (tblContacts
    INNER JOIN tblContactsBuildings ON tblContacts.ContactID = tblContactsBuildings.ContactID)
        ON tblBuildings.BuildingID = tblContactsBuildings.BuildingID)
    INNER JOIN tblMasterContracts1 ON tblBuildings.BuildingID = tblMasterContracts1.BuildingID;
```

Comment: pictures of queries are useless. show the ACTUAL sql

Comment: That's not a query, that's an ER diagram. Even if it was a query, you'd have to explain "unupdateable".

Comment: @patricksweeney: Access users know what "non-updatable" means (from painful experience).

Comment: @patricksweeney, I'm aware of that grammatical flaw. However, it conveyed its meaning properly and also, this isn't a grammar forum. Like I said earlier, please do not litter my post with unwanted, useless contributions and hope to earn points. And by the way, that is a graphical representation of a query.

Comment: @BillyNorbu, while not all pictures are useless, yours is.  As patricksweeny implied, you posted the wrong picture.

Comment: @DanBracuk. That's not a wrong picture. That is the graphical representation of the underlying query. If you're not an Access user, why are you on this thread?

Comment: Because the fact you are using a picture to illustrate what is better expressed in another format has absolutely zero to do with whether or not you are using Access. I wouldn't get combative with people who are trying to tell you what you are doing wrong. We are telling you these things so you can actually ask a GOOD question. In addition, looking at Dan's tags, it sure looks like he's pretty familiar with Access. THAT'S why he's on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

[Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/) composed a list of conditions that make a query non-updatable:

> - It has a GROUP BY clause. A Totals query is always read-only.
> - It has a TRANSFORM clause. A Crosstab query is always read-only.
> - It uses First(), Sum(), Max(), Count(), etc. in the SELECT clause. Queries that aggregate records are read-only.
> - It contains a DISTINCT predicate. Set Unique Values to No in the query's Properties.
> - It involves a UNION. Union queries are always read-only.
> - It has a subquery in the SELECT clause. Uncheck the Show box under your subquery, or use a domain aggregation function instead.
> - It uses JOINs of different directions on multiple tables in the FROM clause. Remove some tables.
> - The fields in a JOIN are not indexed correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.
> - The query's Recordset Type property is Snapshot. Set Recordset Type to "Dynaset" in the query's Properties.
> - The query is based on another query that is read-only (stacked query.)
> - Your permissions are read-only (Access security.)
> - The database is opened read-only, or the file attributes are read-only, or the database is on read-only media (e.g. CD-ROM, network drive without write privileges.)
> - The query calls a VBA function, but the database is not in a trusted location so the code cannot run. (See the yellow box at the top of this Access 2007 page.)
> - The fields that the query outputs are Calcluated fields (Access 2010.)

(Quoted from http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html.)

As you can see, these conditions cannot be verified by looking at the ER diagram alone. As a debugging aid, I recommend removing tables from your query and re-adding them, until the query becomes non-updatable. As soon as this happens, check the list above for the table you have added.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this list. Only the 7th point may apply to my query. What do you reckon will be a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

That's the one:

> The fields in a JOIN are not indexed correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.

You have 1:n relations between the 3 left tables, but no defined relation to `tblMasterContracts1`.

So you should define the foreign key from `tblMasterContracts1` to `tblBuildings`.

Also, `tblContactsBuildings` should have a composite primary key with `ContactID` plus `BuildingID`.